# FineUploader: Secret and Public keys

Tags: fine-uploader

I have read the [documentation](https://blog.fineuploader.com/fine-uploader-s3-upload-directly-to-amazon-s3-from-your-browser-3d9dcdcc0f33), here is what it is saying about the keys:

> You will also need to include your specific AWS access key as a value
>   for the accessKey property above. This is your public AWS key, NOT
>   your secret key. Also, this should be the public key for the IAM user
>   created specifically for Fine Uploader S3, and not your main account
>   key. Your secret key should remain a secret, server-side. Your access
>   key(s) can be found on the security credentials page of your AWS
>   account. Once on that page, you can create new keys or access existing
>   keys under the "Access Keys" section...

So are we here talking about "only" the IAM user created specifically for Fine Uploader S3? or we want also to use the other key that can be found in the Security Credentials of AWS? if we need to use the Security Credential key, where to use it exactly?

I then get confused about the difference between the environment variables that are requested to be set: `AWS_CLIENT_SECRET_KEY`, `AWS_SERVER_SECRET_KEY` and `AWS_SERVER_PUBLIC_KEY`. Are we referring to the same key here? if they is two different keys here, can someone explain to me what exactly is each one of them?

Comment: All 3 different keys. Client secret key is the secret key you created for Fine Uploader with only the necessary permissions. Server secret key is the secret key used by your server. It's probably ok to use an admin key here. Server public key is the public key side of your server key. Not a secret, sharable.

Comment: Thanks Ray, I am using EC2 as my server, so the server private key is the pem file of my EC2 machine I presume then, and I have to copy it to the machine somewhere and provide its path in the AWS_SERVER_SECRET_KEY?

Comment: No - you must provision these keys use the IAM service

Comment: OK so I create a user with AdministratorAccess and I use it, if I understand you correctly.

Comment: That's entirely up to you how much access your server key pair receives. The Fine Uploader pair should be limited to the actions needed by Fine Uploader, such as adding files to a bucket and possibly deleting files (if you use that Fine Uploader feature).

Comment: You also need to be sure to use the Client Public Key/Access Key in your client-side code. Not knowing there had to be 2 separate pairs of keys (the documentation needs better wording) meant I was using the wrong keys on my side.